# Need help to display records

Tags: php, mysql

MY DB structure is this

```
ID | wine_name | wine_description | wine_type | size_id |country_id
```

SQL query I am using to obtain result is

`SELECT * FROM winemeta WHERE wine_name LIKE '%cab%' ORDER BY wine_name ASC`

Below is attach image of search form

[image]

you can see the search results .when i search with word "cab" all result related to the cab show in order by wine name `ASC`.

The requirement is, I need to show the result in `ASC` order as well as Alphabatic order.

In search result 1991 1992 2001 has same name so the accepted result i need is

1991 chateau Monteiena Cab
1992 chateau Monteiena Cab
2001 chateau Monteiena Cab
1992 Dalla Valle Cab
1995 Dalla Valle Cab
Dalla Valle Cab

Please help me with this one i have tried my solutions.

Comment: the result is already in orderby

Comment: Where's the wine year column?

Comment: There is no column for wine year all is name and stored in wine_name

Comment: I strongly suggest you fix that (and grape variety). Then get back to us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is without using any third-party library.

```
SELECT wine_name FROM winemeta order by SUBSTR(wine_name, LENGTH(CONVERT(wine_name, SIGNED)) + 1) asc, CONVERT(wine_name, SIGNED) asc
```

I found some glitches in above query. Here is the modified one.

```
SELECT 
    wine_name
FROM
    winemeta
where
    wine_name like '%cab%'
order by SUBSTR(wine_name,
    if(CONVERT( wine_name , SIGNED) > 0,
        LENGTH(CONVERT( wine_name , SIGNED)) + 2,
        1)) asc , CONVERT( wine_name , SIGNED) asc
```

Comment: That is exactly i am looking for.thanks for your help

Comment: Can you please give me small explanation how it works?

Comment: here is the detailed query. It should explain everything 
SELECT 
    wine_name,
    CONVERT( wine_name , SIGNED) AS num_part,
    SUBSTR(wine_name,
        if(CONVERT( wine_name , SIGNED) > 0,
            LENGTH(CONVERT( wine_name , SIGNED)) + 2,
            1)) AS rest_of_string
FROM
    winemeta
where
    wine_name like '%cab%'
order by SUBSTR(wine_name,
    if(CONVERT( wine_name , SIGNED) > 0,
        LENGTH(CONVERT( wine_name , SIGNED)) + 2,
        1)) asc , CONVERT( wine_name , SIGNED) asc

Answer (score 1):

Mysql does not provide us the regular expression for replace. And for this you have to create a function as :

1. First of all execute following function into your database :

   DELIMITER $$
   CREATE FUNCTION  `regex_replace`(pattern VARCHAR(1000),replacement VARCHAR(1000),original VARCHAR(1000))

   RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
   DETERMINISTIC
   BEGIN 
    DECLARE temp VARCHAR(1000); 
    DECLARE ch VARCHAR(1); 
    DECLARE i INT;
    SET i = 1;
    SET temp = '';
    IF original REGEXP pattern THEN 
     loop_label: LOOP 
      IF i>CHAR_LENGTH(original) THEN
       LEAVE loop_label;
      END IF;
      SET ch = SUBSTRING(original,i,1);
      IF NOT ch REGEXP pattern THEN
       SET temp = CONCAT(temp,ch);
      ELSE
       SET temp = CONCAT(temp,replacement);
      END IF;
      SET i=i+1;
     END LOOP;
    ELSE
     SET temp = original;
    END IF;
    RETURN temp;
   END$$
   DELIMITER ;

It will create a function into your database and after that you can use this function into your query as :

```
SELECT * FROM winemeta WHERE wine_name LIKE '%cab%' ORDER BY regex_replace('[0-9]+','', wine_name) ASC;
```

Comment: I am using this query in as a sql command from php do i need to use this command that you have given in DB

Answer (score 0):

I think these SQL useful to you.

```
SELECT * FROM winemeta WHERE wine_name LIKE '%cab%' 
order by HEX(wine_name) ASC
```

Thank you.

Comment: HEX method is not working as OP's expected result. Cast method was some what matches with results